# How to read sub elements of a plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

i am having a plist file like this now i want to access all three elements( Item 0, Item 1, Item 2 ) which are under under 5K and i want to store it in array. how can i do that ? if any one know the solution please help me to solve this issue. if any this is not clear please post your comments i will replay for it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Expended Form.

[image]

the code i have used

```
-(void)selectLevel
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Planlist" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary * Plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSMutableDictionary * specific;

   NSArray * leveldata = [Plist objectForKey:@"5K"];

    NSArray *complexity = [leveldata objectAtIndex:1];

     NSLog(@"++++++++%@",complexity);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        specific =(NSMutableDictionary *)[leveldata objectAtIndex:i];
         NSLog(@"-------%@",specific);
    }

    NSLog(@"=======-%@",[specific allKeys]);
}
```

Out put that i am getting

[image]

Comment: which element you want to get ?

Comment: "Item 0 Item 1 Item 2" only those elements

Comment: So, you want to store the NSDictionary item0 to 2 which are stored within 5k and with their complete content in a new array?

Comment: not complete content i need that keys alone is it possible?